# \mitGamma not rendering italic

Tags: xetex, texlive, unicode-math, italic

I am rendering small formulae generated from MathML using `unicode-math`.
I just noticed that we produce `\Gamma` where actually want italics, so I  changed that to `\mitGamma` ([unimath-symbols.pdf  Page 87](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf)), but that does not work (still gives normal Gamma).

Tested with both texlive2010 and texlive2017.

Is this a problem with my code/setup or in the package?
My Code:

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[math-style=TeX]{xits-math.otf}
\begin{document}
Gamma: $\Gamma$ \\
mitGamma: $\mitGamma$ \\
\end{document}
```

[image: Gamma and mitGamma rendered with math-style=TeX]
I noticed that changing `math-style=ISO` does result in both Gamma rendering italic (but then I dont know how to get a normal Gamma when I need it).
[image: Gamma and mitGamma rendered with math-style==ISO]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be particularly clear from the documentation, but the input command `\mitGamma` refers to typing the symbol it refers to ().

In turn, the normalisation that `unicode-math` performs then makes this the same as regular `\gamma`.

To force an italic version, you can either write `\itGamma` or `\symit{\Gamma}`.

Comment: I've just added a note to the documentation about this...